# SSH hangs every time an escape character is transmitted

Tags: ssh, remote-access, escaping

I've been asked to continue installation of a freshly installed Debian system. I can log in there through SSH with no problems. But the connection hangs every time the remote shell sends an escape character. For example, all these commands hang the connection:

```
mc
apt-get update
tmux
```

etc. But when I avoid console UI, it works, like in

```
apt-get update | cat
```

Any idea what could be the cause, or what should I investigate?

Answer (score 1):

After all, problem wasn't related to escape characters, but to network in general. Altering MTU seems to fix the problem. Probably when a console UI was started, it transferred too large packet. See also [Why does SCP hang on copying files larger than 1405 bytes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14187/22339).